# Angular ui-router's nested routes not working in ES6 with bable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6

I have multiple modules in Angular and I also use nested routes. There is an `auth` module which also has a sub route `auth.login` the code goes as follows:-

**Login.route.js**

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('auth.login', {
            url: '/login',
            template: require('./login.tpl.html')
        });
}
```

**auth.route.js**

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('auth', {
            url: '/auth',
            template: require('./auth.tpl.html')
        })
}
```

Then inject these into the main module like this according to the folder structure.

```
import auth from './features/auth';
import auth from './features/auth/login';
```

I am not getting any error but apart from the `/` & `/auth` path nothing reflects. If I use `/login` it redirects me to the `/` path.

Kinda weird but UI-Router is not working. Please suggest.

**NOTE: I use BableJS and Webpack for the Development**

Comment: are template requests succeeding in dev tools network? If they fail will cause route rejection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the code you've shown never actually invokes the exported functions.  That might be the root of your problem.

A better way to approach this might be to export the state objects themselves.  In the outermost file, you can then import those state objects, and register them with the `$stateProvider`.  Here's an example:

#### Login.route.js

```
let loginState = {
  // UI-Router allows state definitions to contain the name
  name: 'auth.login', 
  url: '/login',
  template: require('./login.tpl.html')
}

// Just export the state definition; you don't have to register it yet
export default loginState;
```

#### auth.route.js

```
let authState = {
  name: 'auth',
  url: '/auth',
  template: require('./auth.tpl.html')
}
export default authState;
```

#### app.js

This file shows bootstrapping the application.   It imports the state definitions from the child modules, and registers them with the `$stateProvider`.

```
// Now import the state definitions from the other modules
import loginState from './Login.route.js';
import authState from './auth.route.js';

let app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
// create a single config block which registers 
// all the state definitions that were imported
app.config(registerAllStates);

registerAllStates.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
function registerAllStates($stateProvider) {
  // Loop over them and register them with the $stateProvider.
  [loginState, authState].forEach(state => $stateProvider.state(state));
}
```