# ui-router not routing with parent/child components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, components

I'm having trouble finding anything similar to my issue.  I did find [Angular ui-router's nested routes not working in ES6 with bable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932972/angular-ui-routers-nested-routes-not-working-in-es6-with-bable), and they're describing what is happening for me, namely that root-level routing appears to work, but if I try to set up a child route, then nothing shows in the app and the url fails to route.

#### app.config.js

```js
export default function routing ($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

#### index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Learning Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### app.routes.js

```js
export default function AppRoutes ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'home'
    });
}
```

#### home/home.html

```js
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="col-12">Learning Library</h1>
</div>

<add-resource></add-resource>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

#### components/index.js

```js
import HomeComponent from './home';
import LibraryComponent from './library';
import routing from './app.routes';

export default angular.module('app.components', [
  HomeComponent,
  Resource,
  LibraryComponent,
  uirouter
])
  .config(routing)
  .run(($rootScope) => {
    // this is not showing any errors
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', console.log.bind(console));
  })
  .name;
```

#### library.routes.js

```js
export default function LibraryRoutes ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home.library', {
      url: '/library',
      component: 'library'
    })
    .state('library.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'library': 'libraryList'
      },
    });
}
```

#### library/index.js

```js
import ResourceService from '../resource/resource.service';

import routing from './library.routes';

export default angular.module('app.components.library', [
  LibraryListComponent,
  LibraryListResourceComponent,
  ResourceService,
])
  .config(routing)
  .component('library', LibraryComponent)
  .name;
```

#### library/library.html

```js
<div class="row">
  <section class="library col-12">
    <h3>Resources</h3>
    <ui-view="library"></ui-view>
  </section>
</div>
```

The `home` component shows up in the app fine using ui-router 1.0.0, but `library` does not.  If I make the name of the `/library` route just `library` instead of `home.library`, I can then go to `/library` and have the basic library template show up, but the child `libraryList` component still doesn't load.  I've tried various conventions to tag the right containers (`$default@home`, `^`, `$default`, etc) and nothing seems to work.  With the `home.library` name, or with a `library` name and explicit `parent: 'home'`, going to `/library` redirects back to `/`.

Something must be wrong with my config, but I can't place what.  I attempted to switch the way I was writing the states to the suggested method in the linked question, but that seems to produce the same results.  I am using Webpack and transpiling through Babel to ES2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand where I went wrong now; I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how ui-router functioned.

For some reason I thought using states would assign templates to views devoid of routing even if I set the url config, such that going to `/` would show the page entirely assembled according to how I'd set the views, and going to `/library` would show just the library component.  But actually since I set the url to `/library` it would only show up once I routed the page to that url, and since I didn't actually have multiple containers, it was replacing the entire view instead of appending one.  This is a pretty obvious mistake in hindsight.

So nothing showed up appended on the home page because I hadn't set up a second `ui-view` on index to put it there, and the rest of the template didn't show up when I navigated to `/library` because I hadn't told it to be there.  The structure I was really looking for was more like this:

#### app.routes.js

```js
export default function AppRoutes ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        'main': {
          template: require('./home/home.html'),
        },
        'sidebar': {
          template: `
            <!-- this redirect will not refresh the whole page, just changes the sidebar -->
            <button ui-sref="sidebar">Hello</button>
            <ui-view/>
          `,
        },
      }
    })
    .state('sidebar', {
      parent: 'home',
      url: 'sidebar',
      template: '<div>Hello</div>',
      controller: function () {
      }
    })
    // since both library and sidebar are children of home, sidebar shows up on the library descendent pages
    .state('library', {
      parent: 'home',
      abstract: true,
      url: 'library',
      views: {
        'main@': {
          template: '<ui-view/>'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('library.list', {
      url: '/list',
      component: 'libraryList',
    });
}
```

With `index.html` having two `ui-view`s, one named 'main' and one named 'library', and then `library.html` would have a view that the list would be inserted into.

The redirects seemed to be happening because of my routing configuration being set to `otherwise` and something about the configuration was invalid, making the route invalid, so redirecting it back to the root.